# Remote JNDI lookup using only Java jars (without thin clients of WebLogic/Jboss etc)

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0

I want to perform remote EJB lookup from Spring or standalone Java, as my application executes as standalone, I cannot use any vendor jars like WebLogic/Jboss thin clients. How can perform remote EJB lookup using Java specification jars or Spring only?

I tried to use `javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory` but below error at run time.

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

By using spring you can do that by following java config:

```
@Configuration
public class EJBConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean fooService(){
        LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setBusinessInterface(FooService.class);
        factory.setJndiName("java:global/my_ear/my_jar/FooServiceBean");
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Or using xml

```
<bean id="fooService"
        class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:global/my_ear/my_jar/FooServiceBean"/>
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.company.ejb.FooService"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: using this i can connect to only local EJB's but my case is to lookup remote EJB(this ejb is deployed in other container in remote server), in this case how to get InitialContext, which package of java.naming.factory.initial should i use now?

Comment: Similarly, for accessing the Remote Stateless Session Bean, the class SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean has to be used instead of LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean. The properties 'jndiName' and 'businessInterface' will still be applicable.

Comment: Shi, it doesnt work because spring does not know which server to connect and load the context as we are not loading any context.  Spring should get jndiProperties to load environment-ref and use this reference for jee:lookup. 
if i use weblogic context factory it is working, but as per project specifications, i cant use any vendor related unless it comes by default from java or spring.

Comment: FYI:-
if i simply use Spring Remote stateless bean, i will get below exception
spring is not a provider for ejb lookup, it should know the environment properties and once context is created then spring internally does the ejb lookup to get business interface.



Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: Thanks for dzone link
here it loads the context:-
this is openEJB jar which is not either from java or spring, do we have any provider implementation from java or spring only???

 Properties env = new Properties();
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
  env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ejbd://localhost:4201");
  ctx = new InitialContext(env);

Comment: When you are trying to connect remote jndi application from a provider, the provider should provide you a jndi.properties file which contains jndi specific information. You need to read that file using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and set the values inside jndiTemplate configuration. That's it.

Comment: Shi, looks like you are not aware of Factory implementation, in the jndi properties what is the value you are using for context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY?
 is the the java provider or spring, or some vendor like weblogic, jboss, openEJB etc...
my question is regarding that i need either java provider or spring provider here, if you are not aware , its ok but i request you to not reply with generic answers unrelated to question.

Comment: Upon Further analysis, there is no provider from java or spring , we either have to implement using java.io programming or use any vendor clients like weblogic, jBoss, websphere, openEjb etc...
Thanks all........